# Презентационный бар

Tags: javascript

http://www.google.com/doubleclick/#tab=overview
На этой странице есть презентационный бар, в самом начале, при клике в адресе меняется якорь, да еще и JS переключает табы. Как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите, а что такого особенного? сделать:

```
<a href="#tab=1234">mytab</a>
```

ну а при загрузке страницы, получить через JS адресную строку, отпарсить значение #tab, и показать нужный див. Что Вас так смутило? Якорь получить можно, примерно так:

```
function getAnc() { 
   return (document.URL.split('#').length > 1) ? document.URL.split('#')[1] : null;
}
```

P.S> хотя там скорее всего `html5 history api`, подробнее тут: [HTML5 History API уже сегодня и без ограничений](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144071/). Да вы и сами это знаете ;)